# How to build bootstrap version 4 so that the CSS only contains specific parts, such as grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap version 3 has a nifty web tool, on their site, that lets you customize the CSS file. You can choose which styles the CSS file will include, such as the grid styles, code styles, or specific components such as navbars, etc.

The bootstrap version 4 site does not have this, yet. I'm trying to figure out how to build this type of CSS file using the cloned repository.

How can I build bootstrap version 4 so that the CSS file only contains the specific styles that I need?

Comment: If you're downloading the full source, you would be better off utilizing SASS to grab only what you want and compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Download bootstrap source from github https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap there is button in green to download if you don't have git.
(2) Install ruby and sass follow instructions at http://sass-lang.com/install
(3) cd into scss folder of the source you've downloaded
(4) change bootstrap.scss file to import only components you need for example if you dont need card remove `@import "card"`
(5) In terminal or command prompt cd into scss folder
(6) Run sass bootstrap.scss bootstrap-custom.css instead of bootstrap-custom you can put any name you want
(7) file named bootstrap-custom.css is generated use it however you want;